# sible resular expression for multiple expression

Tags: regex

```
/^Mozilla.*Android.*SonySGP311/si 
/^Mozilla.*Android.*Sony Tablet P/si
/^Mozilla.*Android.*SGPT12/si
/^Mozilla.*Android.*SGP311/si 
/^Mozilla.*Android.*Transformer/si
/^Mozilla.*linux.*KFOT.*Silk/si
 /^Mozilla.*linux.*KFJWA.*Silk/si
```

How can I put all the above regular expressions in to single regular expression so that it matches with all the above regexes ?

Comment: I've had a bit enough of `how to combine these regexes` questions. Could someone point or create a canonical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do :

```
^(Mozilla.*Android.*(SonySGP311|Sony Tablet P|SGPT12|SGP311|Transformer)|Mozilla.*linux.*(KFOT.*Silk|KFJWA.*Silk))$
```

demo here :  http://regex101.com/r/pG0cV5

updated on suggestion of @Babyy

Comment: @Babyy so what are you saying? the op wants that only read the questin carefully, he wants all the conditions into onw

Comment: @aelor : but in question `SGPT12` can comin after `Android.*` not coming after linux !!